# How would I go about grafting Japanese Maples?

Tags: japanese-maple, grafting

I would like to plant a nice weeping Japanese Maple in my yard, but the nice ones at the nursery are quite expensive.  Some friends have exactly the type of Japanese Maple that I would like in my yard.  How would I go about grafting a branch into a tree that I could plant in my yard? What is the process and how long does it usually take?

Comment: There is a wonderful write up on [Grafting at Maplestone Ornamentals](http://www.maplestoneornamentals.com/grafting_japanese_maples.cfm). Micah is ahead of the pack when it comes to grafting, so if you have questions after reading his page, try the facebook page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

eHow has a good article on [how to graft a japanese maple](http://www.ehow.com/how_4746374_graft-japanese-maple.html) that you may find useful.

> 1. Timing is key when you are grafting a Japanese maple. Cut dormant
>      scions (wood) in late winter or in mid
>      to late summer, make sure the wood is
>      firm and ideally about the thickness
>      of a pencil (smaller scions can be
>      used as well). Take cuttings from the
>      desired Japanese Maple cultivar
>      (Bloodgood, Red Dragon etc..) Make the
>      cuttings about four to six inches and
>      be sure they have at least two to
>      three buds. Place the cuttings in a
>      moistened paper towel, put in a
>      plastic bag and label the bag. Keep
>      refrigerated until you are ready to
>      graft. (Scion wood can last about 2
>      months in refrigeration). If you can
>      use scion wood on the same day it will
>      increase your success rate.
> 2. You may graft a Japanese Maple as early as late July continuing through
>      March. Select a healthy Japanese maple
>      to be used as your understock. Ideally
>      it should be about the thickness of a
>      pencil but you may use a smaller or
>      larger understock. Find a long smooth,
>      straight section on your understock
>      where you will make your first cut.
> 3. Make a 15 degree slanting one inch cut on the understock of the Japanese
>      Maple. The cut should be a smooth
>      single stroke. Now cut the scion wood
>      on both sides at 45 degree angles to
>      match the understock cut. Insert the
>      scion under the flap on the understock
>      and align the scion at the edge so
>      that the cambium layers match. The
>      cambium Layer is the thin green layer
>      located just below the bark.
> 4. Use the grafting rubbers or grafting tape. Grafting rubbers are
>      preferred. Begin wrapping at the base
>      of the Japanese Maple graft to secure
>      the end of the grafting rubber by
>      overlapping the first 2 wraps. Slowly
>      work your way up the graft union
>      overlapping as you go while keeping
>      tension on the grafting rubber. This
>      secures the scion in position. As you
>      complete the last wrap, secure rubber
>      with a loop end of rubber under itself
>      to secure.
> 5. Take plastic bag and moisten the inside with fungicidal water and place
>      over the scion to just below graft and
>      secure with a tie or staples. This
>      creates high humidity until the graft
>      has joined. The graft should take in
>      three to five weeks after joining the
>      graft.
> 6. Remove the top of the rootstock just above the graft once it has
>      taken. Cut off any stems below your
>      graft union as they may overtake your
>      graft.

Comment: Could you summarize it (in addition to the link, not in place of it) in case the link goes down? Thanks!

Comment: A wholesale copy paste, even as a quote, is not a summary. A small quote is good, quoting the whole article is bad.